# Seperating html form from php file

Tags: php, html

Previously I wrote a PHP code that includes an HTML form. So basically, the user inputs info in the HTML form and if all necessary input is filled, then the PHP file directs information to another PHP file. [This is the HTML form I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVBBt.png) This is the PHP File code (I will only put one variable of the form so that it's easier to understand:

```
                                                                    <?php
                                                                session_start();
                                                                include('config/db_connect.php');
                                                                    $Telephone = '';
                                                                    $errors = array('Telephone' => '');
                                                                    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                                                                        // check Telephone
                                                                        if(empty($_POST['Telephone'])){
                                                                            $errors['Telephone'] = 'A Telephone number is required';
                                                                        } else{
                                                                            $Telephone = $_POST['Telephone'];
                                                                            $_SESSION['Telephone'] = $Telephone;
                                                                            if(!filter_var($Telephone, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)){
                                                                                $errors['Telephone'] = 'Telephone must be a valid Telephone number';
                                                                            }
                                                            
                                                                if(array_filter($errors)){
                                                                    //echo 'errors in form';
                                                                } else {
                                                                    // escape sql chars
                                                                    header('Location: OTP.php');    
                                                                }
                                                                        } // end POST check
                                                                    ?>

                                                                    <!DOCTYPE html>
                                                                    <html>
                                                                    <?php include('templates/header.php'); ?>
                                                                        <section class="container grey-text">
                                                                            <h4 class="center">Add a form</h4>
                                                                            <body>
                                                                            <form class="white" action="add.php" method="POST">
                                                                                <label style="font-size: 16px">Your Telephone</label>
                                                                                <input type="text" name="Telephone" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($Telephone) ?>">
                                                                                <div class="red-text"><?php echo $errors['Telephone']; ?></div><p></p>
                                                                                <div class="center">
                                                                                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn brand z-depth-0">
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </form>
                                                                            </body>
                                                                        </section>
                                                                        <?php include('templates/footer.php'); ?>
                                                                    </html>
```

Anyway, due to some reason, now I need to make the HTML form in a separate HTML file. So when users inputs the data in that form, the data has to be transferred to the PHP file I mentioned above and the innit['submit'] has to take place to further process it from there. In other words, previously the HTML form within the PHP file was filled and when 'submit' was clicked, the PHP file redirected it to another PHP file, but now the HTML form is in a HTML file itself and I want that when the form in that file has a click on 'submit', the PHP file is forced to follow the same procedure as it did previously. However, I cannot make the HTML file transfer the info to PHP and the PHP to directly go into the innit['submit'] function.

Here's the HTML part of the code (in the new HTML file):

```
<form action="work/add.php" method="POST">
<div id="Group_206">
        <div id="Text_ca">
            <span>電話號碼</span>
        </div>
        <input class="TextBox03" type="text" id="Telephone" name="Telephone">
        <div id="Phone_name_position">
        </div>
    <div id="Group_159_m">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
    </div>
```

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` will never be triggered, there is no element with `name="submit"`

Comment: Please format your question to a more readable form

Comment: Well, nothing wrong there form the HTML side of things. You are declaring a form and a target to submit the form to. However, as brombeer already correctly stated, you may want to check your 'isset' condition. Seeing how the 'processing page' will only be called from POST, do you need the isset at all? And if so, maybe check for a form element that actually has a name?

Comment: did you close that form tag ?

Comment: Got my answer. Brombeer's answer is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is as given in the [comment by brombeer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69491260/seperating-html-form-from-php-file/69505686#comment122827149_69491260):

> `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` will never be triggered, there is no
> HTML element with `name="submit"` –  brombeer